# Error: Image Noise detection in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am getting error while implementing a simple idea for noise detection in an image. Let `I` denote  noisy  image  and  for  each  pixel of  `I`  is represented by `I(x,y)`. A sliding window of size `3X3` centered at `I(x, y)` is defined. At first, we estimate that the center pixel of window is noise or not. To differ the noise and signal, we calculate the mean `m` and standard deviation `s` of the window. If the pixel is between `m-s` and `m+s`, then it is a signal otherwise noise and we will apply median filter.

Algorithm:

1. Read an image `I`.
2. Take a sliding window or mask of size `3X3`.
3. Calculate the mean `m` and standard deviation `s` from the mask.
4. Calculate the threshold as follows: `t1 = m-s` and `t2 = m+s`
5. `IF t1 <= I(x,y) and I(x,y) <= t2,  THEN Result(x,y) = I(x,y)  ELSE Result(x, y) = medfilt2(I(x,y)`
6. Repeat the step 3 , 4 and 5 on entire Image.
7. Display the resultant image.

I tried to implement this algorithm as follows

```
clc;
close all;
clear all;

I=imread('lena.jpg');
I=rgb2gray(I);

Out = blockproc(I,[3 3],@(x) noisedetection(x.data(:)));

imshow(out);
```

The function `noisedetection` is given as below:

```
function x=noisedetection(y)
s=std2(y(:)); % Calculating Standard deviation
m=mean2(y(:)); % Calulating Mean
t1=m-s; % Threshold 1
t2=m+s; % Threshold 2
[m n]=size(y);

for i=1:m
    for j=1:n


if (t1<=y(i,j) & y(i,j)<=t2)
    iout(i,j)=y(i,j)
else
    iout(i,j)=medfilt2(y(i,j)) % Filtering only when the pixel does not fall in the interval [t1,t2] 
end
    end
end
x=iout
```

But I am getting the following error

```
    Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in blockprocInMemory (line 151)
    b(last_row_start:end,last_col_start:end,:) = lr_output;

Error in blockproc (line 237)
    result_image = blockprocInMemory(source,fun,options);

Error in detection (line 8)
Out = blockproc(I,[3 3],@(x) noisedetection(x.data(:)));
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. blockproc gives you distinct blocks. Instead use nlfilter.
2. `iout(i,j)=medfilt2(y(i,j))`  is a wrong statement. medfilt2 only does median filtering, it doesn't give you the median. To get the median value, just use `median(y(:))`.
3. This is wrong : `(t1<=y(i,j) & y(i,j)<=t2)` .

Plus you have cross-posted. Check out : https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/15033/error-image-noise-detection-in-matlab/15036?noredirect=1#comment25759_15036

Explanation to $3^rd$ is given in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

This means you did not assign anything to your output parameter. I guess you should assign to `x` rather then `iout (i, j)`

Comment: updated by adding x=iout in function, now getting "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch."

Comment: am I implementing it in a correct way? Or do we have any other way to implement this?